# Open modal in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I am trying to use the modal from the following website(first example): http://jquerymodal.com/

Is there a way to open the modal using js? As I am opening the modal if the form on my page was field correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include JQuery and call the library links, this full example for what you need

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Modal HTML embedded directly into document -->
  <div id="ex1" class="modal">
    <p>Thanks for clicking. That felt good.</p>
    <a href="#" rel="modal:close">Close</a>
  </div>


<!-- Remember to include jQuery :) -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Modal -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```